# redux form, Field component issues

Tags: redux-form

I have some issues using "Field" component in Redux Form in my code. Just follow the simple example on redux-form website.

```
/* MyForm.jsx */
...
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class MyForm extends Component {
    ...
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(...)}>
        <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <div>
                <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm'
})(MyForm);
```

Here is the parent component that use the redux form.

```
/* page.jsx */
import MyForm from './MyForm';
...
<MyForm/>
...
```

The form does not render and in console the error says:

*`React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).`*

*`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`*

However, if I use material-ui or bootstrap form field, it works fine.

I mounted the form reducer before render the form:

```
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
const myReducer = combineReducers({
    ...
    form: formReducer
});
```

Any ideas why Fields component does not work?

Thanks,

Comment: what version of redux form are you using?

Comment: have you tried upgrading to v 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading your redux to 6.0. Field component started at v6.0, I believe.

Comment: Yes, upgrade to 6.0.1 resolved the Field error. However, in 6.0.1, the format of form fields has been changed from Array to Object. so what will be the correct format for my current fields?                                  formFields = [
  'firstname',
  'lastname',
  'password'
]

Comment: formFields={[ 'firstname', 'lastname' , 'password' ]}

Comment: I see an example here: http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/docs/api/Fields.md/  .But haven't seen doc or usage examples about it. Thanks,